# What is Special Chakra NFT from Comics NFT

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

The **Chakra NFT** from comics is the trendsetter of recent days in the crypto space. The NFT lineups are making a huge difference here and to say in precise, Special chakra NFT of the crypto space will have a huge direct impact on the mass.